# Correct way to calculate HVL of a given beam (poly)

Tags: x-rays

Hello I'm trying to calculate the HVL of a beam of whom I know everything but a particular filtration.

At the moment I tried by inverting the formula ($I=I_0 e^{- \mu x}$), integrating over all the energies, but I've found no results, a friend suggested using the HVL calculated from Dose in air but I can't find literature online.

Comment: Even though there might be people who immediately know them, consider to spell out your acronyms, at least the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of calculating HVL (half value layer) from three different exposure measurements

HVL = $\frac{{t_b} ln(\frac{2E_a}{E_0}) - {t_a} ln(\frac{2E_b}{E_0})}{ln(\frac{E_a}{E_b})}$

where

- $E_0$ = exposure measurement with no aluminum in the beam
- $E_a$ = exposure measurement with $t_a$ mm aluminum in the beam.  $t_a$ is enough aluminum so that $E_a$ is just above $E_0$/2.
- $E_b$ = exposure measurement with $t_b$ mm aluminum in the beam.  $t_b$ is enough aluminum so that $E_b$ is just below $E_0$/2.

If you have a series of exposure measurements obtained with different attenuator thicknesses, determining HVL is pretty trivial using graphical methods too.

If all you have is the energy spectrum of an imaginary x-ray beam, $HVL = \frac{ln(2)}{\mu}$

where $\mu = \mu(E)$ is the energy dependent linear attenuation coefficient for whatever substance you want the HVL for.  Maybe a weighted sum of $\mu$ over the energy range of your x-ray spectrum would give you a reasonable answer.